# Javascript: how can i add data field to all the links in a HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a html page where i have to add  data-fancybox="gallery" to all the links in a page to display a image in a fancybox.

right now i am adding manually to all the links in each page.

how can i add automatically data-fancybox="gallery" to all the links through javascript/Jquery?

Example:

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://example.com/Capture.JPG" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="621" data-original-width="603" height="640" src="https://example.com/Capture.JPG" width="620" /></a>
```

Comment: Can you use jquery?

Comment: yes ...can u give me an example?

Comment: Are all links that needs to be hooked to the fancybox plugin containing img tags? Like `<a href="...url.."><img src="..."/><a/>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use JQuery to loop through each `<a>` element and add a data attribute like this:

```
$("a").each(function ()
{
    $(this).attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery');
});
```

**EDIT**

If you want to add it only to certain `<a>` elements (like inside a container) look at this example:

(this adds the fancybox data-attribute only to the elements which are inside the `.do-add-fancybox` container)

```js
$(".do-add-fancybox a").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="do-not-add-fancybox">
    <p>
      Hello World
    </p>
    <a href="Something">test</a>
  </div>

  <div class="do-add-fancybox">
    <p>
      Hello World, 2
    </p>
    <a href="my Link">test</a>
    <a href="my Link2">test</a>
    <a href="my Link3">test</a>
    <a href="my Link4">test</a>
    <a href="my Link5">test</a>
    <a href="my Link6">test</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: why you use each when there is 1 absolute gallery value to put can you explain why use each instead 
`$("a").attr('data-fancybox','gallery')` this?

Comment: this works fine but it makes all other links on the page to load inside fancybox ...i mean menu like home,about us,contactus. 

i want to add to links only with img

Comment: @hahah Yeah, that's what you asked for. This basically adds the data attribute to ALL links on your webpage. If you want it to be added to links with a certain class, id or inside a certain container just ask for that and I'll help you

Comment: yes sorry forgot to mention...so how can i avoid this?

Comment: See my answer @haha

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful.

```js
/*data-fancybox="gallery"*/

var all_anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i=0; i < all_anchors.length; i++){
  all_anchors[i].setAttribute("data-fancybox", "gallery")
}

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
```

```html
<a  href="https://example.com/Capture.JPG" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"></a>

<a  href="https://example.com/Capture.JPG" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML syntax:

```
<article
  id="electriccars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

JavaScript access:

```
var article = document.getElementById('electriccars');

article.dataset.columns // "3"
article.dataset.indexNumber // "12314"
article.dataset.parent // "cars"
```

CSS access:

```
article::before {
  content: attr(data-parent);
}
```

reference link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
document.body.getElementsByTagName("a").setAttribute("data-fancybox", "gallery");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").attr('data-fancybox','gallery') // this should add gallery to all a link under named data-fancybox

$("a[href]").attr('data-fancybox','gallery') // this should add gallery to a tag with only href inside a link under named data-fancybox
```

> To me Case like this absolute value use above selector instead of
>   each. You know value to add your a link unless value to add different
>   for each time use each otherwise above code doing fine